# How do I configure CLion to show final executable size after build?

Tags: clion, jetbrains-ide

Is there a setting in CLion to have the size of the final executable show after a build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use external tools for it. Please try to do the following:

1. Edit Run configuration
2. Add before lunch new action (Run External tool).

For example, you can use size.exe MinGW tool if you on the Windows platform.

`<path_to_mingw>\bin\size.exe $CMakeCurrentProductFile$`

3. Run the build configuration